# Typescript - Sub class function that calls super returns parent class type

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I am confused by the inheritance scheme in typescript. I seem to be unable to return the child type when making a call to super. Can someone explain why this example does not return the child type? What is the effect of `as`? Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

```
class Parent {
    _value: number
    constructor(value: number){
        this._value = value
    }
    add(x: Parent): Parent {
        return new Parent(x._value + this._value)
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(value: number) {
        super(value)
    }
    add(x: Child): Child {
        return super.add(x) as Child
    }
}

let a = new Child(10)
let b = new Child(5)
let c = a.add(b)

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
console.log(c)
```

Output:

```
Child { _value: 10 }
Child { _value: 5 }
Parent { _value: 15 }
```

Comment: The `as` keyword is just for the compiler to understand the *alleged* type. It does not transform from A to B.

Comment: In TS, `as` and `<>` should never have been referred to as "Casting" (as you're trying to do) in the first place, but "Type assertors". These do not exist in the runtime, and are only a way for you to provide hints to the compiler on how you want your code to be analyzed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "new this.constructor()" for this kind of polymorphism. And return type as "this" for TypeScript. After this, you do not need to override the method.